# Слово "но" в кавычках

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

*У нас единственное "но" – кто будет главный?*

Правильно ли "но" в кавычках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ребята, я в ауте:

Справка Грамоты.ру кавычек не велит (я всегда ставила).

[Вопрос № 223533](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=223533%20)

> Ответьте, пожалуйста: если бы не одно "но", но надо в кавычках
>   писать?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Кавычки не нужны.

---

[Вопрос № 225895](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=225895)

> Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать фразу: только
>   есть одно "но" или только есть одно но.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Кавычки не требуются.
>
> ---

[Вопрос № 227437](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=227437)

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать словосочетание одно но
>   (но с кавычками или без)?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Правильно без кавычек.
>
> ---

Вопрос-ответ последний - разъяснительный.

**[Вопрос № 278745](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=278745)**

> Здравствуйте, искала ответ по поводу верного написания *одно "но"*. И
>   в ваших ответах обнаружила два варианта (ниже). Как все-таки правильно
>   - с кавычками или без: есть только одно "но" (но)?
>
> Вопрос № 225895
>
> Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать фразу: только
>   есть одно "но" или только есть одно но. Татьяна
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Кавычки не требуются.
>
> Вопрос № 223533
>
> Ответьте, пожалуйста: если бы не одно "но", но надо в кавычках писать?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Корректно с кавычками.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Словарная фиксация – без кавычек. Вот фрагмент словарной статьи
>   «Большого толкового словаря русского языка» под ред. С. А. Кузнецова:
>
> **Но**, *неизм.; ср*. Обстоятельство, мешающее чему-л., препятствие; возражение. *Есть маленькое но. Никаких но – выполняйте задание.
>   Давайте без всяких но. Без но не получится. В этом деле очень много
>   но.*
>
> То же – в «Толковом словаре русского языка» под ред. С. И. Ожегова и
>   Н. Ю. Шведовой:
>
> **Но**, *нескл. ср*. Возражение, препятствие (разг.) *Есть маленькое но. Никаких но – выполняйте приказ.*
>
> Ответ на вопрос № 223533 исправлен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто-нибудь из других авторов г-на Кузнецова поддерживает? Помню, у него как у составителя уже встречались спорные места.

Comment: Для сравнения. _Точки над "и"_ - пишется с кавычками (по данным из разных словарей).

Comment: "И" - название буквы, незакавыченное, в предложении смотрелось бы как инородное вкрапление (союз, например), к тому же «i», латиницей. Про поддержку Кузнецова не знаю, но Справка переделала прежние ответы на единодушное "да" без кавычек (с "да" тот же случай?! О_о) и: ***То же – в «Толковом словаре русского языка» под ред. С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой***! А вообще - я за кавычки! И буду их ставить!

Comment: И я буду - иначе с первого раза правильно не прочитать. Выходит, раньше и "Грамота" была на правильном пути? И до чего же составители подводят своих редакторов!

Comment: Я тоже за кавычки. (Кстати, в этом предложении "за" без кавычек, а слово "кавычки" надо заковычивать?)

Comment: На мой взгляд, кавычки необходимы в порядке "извинения" за нестандартное использование "но" - в качестве _существительного_ (это посильнее цитирования буквы "и"). Они обращают внимание на необходимость особого восприятия при прочтении.

Comment: Полностью согласная я.

Answer (score 4):

Слово выделяется разными способами — курсивом, жирностью, разрядкой. В том числе, и кавычками. Это самое доступное и распространённое выделение.

> Единственное «но» ― меняется ОДУ и объем ресурса.
>
> Единственное «но»: такой антураж и такой драматургический конфликт.
>
> Пока проблем нет. Единственное НО!!! верхний рычаг подвески был не
>   затянут.